# Django can't load ckeditor in the admin page

Tags: django, django-models, ckeditor

This is my `settings.py` file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'search.apps.SearchConfig',
    'user.apps.UserConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django_node_assets',
    'ckeditor',
    'ckeditor_uploader',
]

CKEDITOR_BASEPATH = "./search/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/"
CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "/media/"
```

This is the `models.py` file

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

class Content(models.Model):
    heading = models.ForeignKey(SubTopics, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = RichTextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.heading.heading
```

This rich text editor is not showing on the admin page. Even no text field is shown on the page, just blank space.

I got the solution.
remove `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` and it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to collect the static files. Use the command below in the terminal

```py
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: did you add the chkeditor urls in your project `urls.py` file @MeetGondaliya

Comment: Yes I added it. But I got what was causing the trouble. I just have to remove the line from `settings.py` which is `CKEDITOR_BASEPATH` variable and it worked.

Comment: glad you figured it out

Comment: thanks for your effort to solve this problem :)